# Why does ReSharper report "expression is always false"? (for boolean Equals true true)

Tags: resharper, resharper-2018

The unit test passing appears to contradict the inspection claim.

There are a lot of false reports of bugs with this inspection.

```
    public void Foo2()
    {
        bool objA = true;
        bool objB = true;

        var result1 = Equals(objA, objB);
        Assert.Equal(true, result1);
    }
```

[image: inspection text contradicts unit test result]

Using:

- JetBrains ReSharper Ultimate 2018.2.1 Build 182.0.20180829.63240
- Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2017 Version 15.8.9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a ReSharper bug: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-471261

It was fixed in ReSharper 2018.2.2.